# How to get Facebook user access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

After hours of Googling and research, I cant find out how to get the facebook user access token. I have an app which wants to access my posts. I have used `facebook php sdk` and `Graph Api call`, but in both the cases what I got is an app access token. The error when I used this token to get the posts is

`Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource.`

I found it needs user access token with the permissions. Eventually I got a way to get the user access token. I have used the `Graph API Explorer` to get a shot lived user access token and then I have extended it using `expires` parameter and my app is working well. I am still searching for a way to get the user access token by `Graph API` call or `PHP SDK`.

I want to get the user access token for my own Facebook account. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the example given by the PHP SDK https://raw.github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/master/examples/example.php then you should be able to understand how to login.

Also see the Getting Started version of the PHP SDK in developers.facebook.com https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/

The gist of it is that the user logs in via the link provided from the `getLoginUrl()` method after which the user will go through an authentication flow similar to the flow you experienced when requesting an access token from the Graph API Explorer

[image: Flow for Authorization]

Comment: Okay I will go through. I need the user access token for only my Facebook account.